# How to select specific rows from buttons created in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, rows

I have created a grid of buttons using a for loop (much more efficient for it's purpose), however I want to be able to say that for example, if any button on the second row is chosen, it will have a different command to if a button on the first row was chosen.

```
    curDay = 1

    for i in range(35):
        if len(rows[0].slaves()) == 7:
            rows.pop(0)
        temp = ButtonsWrap(rows[0], curMonth,curDay,text='',height=1,width=2)
        temp.button.pack(side='left')
        buttons.append(temp)
        if curDay <= months[curMonth]:
            temp.button.config(text=curDay,command=lambda:[f() for f in[lambda: bid(i),temp.popup]])
            curDay += 1

        def bid(self):
            print(i)
```

This is where the buttons are created, if that helps anyone identify how to get what I'm after.

A better alternative would be to print the number of the button that is chosen, but I'm not sure if that's possible due to the text of the buttons never being constant in the loop.

Comment: Have you tried lambda?
temp.button.config(text=curDay, command=lambda: print(i))

Comment: @nicknick how would this work can I ask? I’ll need multiple commands as it’s all depending on what is row is chosen.

Comment: instead of __print__ use use needed function. instead of __i__ use row number. something like temp.button.config(text=curDay, command=lambda row_number: temp.popup(row_number)).

Comment: @nicknick I think this will work however it constantly just prints 34, rather than the row number. Any help?

Comment: *"it constantly just prints 34"*: [Edit] your Question and show how you did the `command:lamda:..`

Comment: @protej, okay sorry. can you paste full buttons code (with imports, mainloop etc.), just to copy-paste and solve that problem?

Comment: @stovfl the code's been edited to how it currently looks.

Comment: @nicknick https://pastebin.com/seM90ZPY here's a pastebin link of the full code relevant to this situation

Comment: *"how it currently looks"*: A `loop` doesn't make sense?. Explain in detail why do you use a `loop`.

Comment: @stovfl I use a loop because it appeared more efficient as a method of creating the buttons, so that if the user chose the second month in the dropdown (february) then it would create 28 buttons as the dictionary tells the loops how many days are in each month. It's also so that it reduces the needed lines of code to write in every single button for each month. The purpose is to act as a calendar/date picker. If It still doesn't make sense I'll try to explain further.

Comment: I'm talking about this loop in loop: `command=lambda:[f() for f in[lambda: bid(i),temp.popup]]`, you too?

Comment: @stovfl ah my mistake. I believe it’s just to allow two commands to be called instead of only one, but using that method of the loop is the only way I’m aware of.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def makeCalendar(blank):
    curMonth = int(dropMonths.get())

    for i in buttons:
        if i.thing:
            i.thing.destroy()
    for i in newFrame.slaves():
        i.destroy()

    rows = [Frame(newFrame) for i in range(5)]
    [i.pack() for i in rows]

    curDay = 1

    for i in range(35):
        if len(rows[0].slaves()) == 7:
            rows.pop(0)
        temp_button = ButtonsWrap(rows[0], curMonth, curDay, text='', height=1,
                           width=2)
        temp_button.button.pack(side='left')
        if curDay <= months[curMonth]:
            temp_button.button.configure(text=curDay, command=lambda TMP=i: bid(TMP))
            curDay += 1

        buttons.append(temp_button)

def bid(i):
    print(i)
```

And your code very hard to read, but that is not about your question.

Comment: I'm confused as to what actually gets printed with this, as it appears to be random numbers? I tried clicking a few buttons and got outputs ranging from 0-24

Comment: i don't know what is __i__ mean too. change __i__ to needed variable

Comment: That's my problem really, I'm unsure how to pinpoint which bit of the code is making each row since it's been made in a loop, so I can't tell what variable I need to replace i with.

Comment: I’m unsure as to what that is sorry

Comment: Okay. You just need to know what you code and use right variable. Suddenly, i cant help with this